# Smartsheet avoiding infinite loop in node

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api-2.0

Does anyone know how to add a change agent header for node.js to the smartsheet api call?  In the api documentation https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#preventing-infinite-loops there is no implementation, only an example in Ruby.  Using the same setup doesn't get picked up by the webhook so running any changes from the API right now results in an infinite loop.

```
let options = {
      sheetId: SHEET_ID,
      body: body,
      header_overrides: {'Smartsheet-Change-Agent': 'MyChangeAgent'}
    };

smartsheet.sheets.updateRow(options);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out-

```
let options = {
  sheetId: SHEET_ID,
  body: body,
  changeAgent: 'MyChangeAgent'
};

smartsheet.sheets.updateRow(options);
```